# calcular valores en una vista

Tags: laravel, controller

Hola buenas tengo una vista en la que hago un filtro de matriculas de alumnos por mes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y tengo algunas dudas:

1) Lo mas importante es que me calcule el total de alumnos matriculados y que me sume los montos del mes seleccionado 
 Cuando hago un dd($matriculas) en mi controlador me muestra lo siguiente

```html
LengthAwarePaginator {#411 ▼
  #total: 5
  #lastPage: 1
  #items: Collection {#413 ▶}
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "http://localhost:8000/matriculas/reportes"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

Como puedo mostrar ese #total en la vista, y como puedo sumar los montos y mostrarlos abajo?? Ayuda porfavor.

Mi controlador

```
public function reportes(Request $request)
{
    $matriculas = Matricula::search($request->fecha)->orderBy('created_at','DSC')->paginate(10);
    return view('matriculas/reportes')->with('matriculas',$matriculas);
}
```

y la vista

```html
@section('content')

 {!! Form::open(['URL' => 'matriculas/reportes', 'method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'navbar-form pull-left']) !!}
 
   {!! Form::label('fecha','Mes ')!!}
      <select name="fecha">
        <option value="0">Seleccione....</option> 
     <option value="1">Enero</option>
     <option value="2">Febrero</option>
     <option value="3">Marzo</option>
     <option value="4">Abril</option>
     <option value="5">Mayo</option>
     <option value="6">Junio</option>
     <option value="7">Julio</option>
     <option value="8">Agosto</option>
     <option value="9">Septiembre</option>
     <option value="10">Octubre</option>
     <option value="11">Noviembre</option>
     <option value="12">Diciembre</option>
   </select>
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
 {!! Form::close() !!}<br><br><br>


 

<div class="panel panel-primary">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
   <th>Fecha</th>
   <th>Rut</th>
   <th>Estado</th>
   <th>Monto</th>
   <th>Opciones</th>
   
  </tr>
   @foreach ($matriculas as $m)
    <tr>
     <td>{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($m->fecha)->format('d-m-Y') }}</td>
     <td>{{ $m->alumno->rut }}</td>
     <td>{{ $m->estado}}</td>
     <td>$ {{ $m->monto }}</td>
     <td><a href="{{route('matriculas.show', $m->id)}}" class="btn btn-info" ><span class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>

      
    </tr>
    @include('matriculas.modal')
   @endforeach

 </table>
 </div>

 
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"">
      <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('', '') !!}
       
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"">
      <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('Alumnos Matriculados', 'Alumnos Matriculados') !!}
       {!! Form::text('n1', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
      </div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"">
      <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('Total', 'Total') !!}
       {!! Form::text('Total', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  
 
 
@endif
@endsection
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obtener el conteo de registros, utiliza el método `count()` en la colección:

```
$alumnos = $matriculas->count();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-count

---

Para obtener la suma de los montos, utiliza el método `sum()` en la propiedad `monto` de la colección:

```
$total = $matriculas->sum('monto');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sum

Comment: Gracias maestro